# receiving an error from applying filter function to multiple datasets using lappy

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, lapply

I tried to apply a function to multiple datasets using the lapply function. More specifically, I tried to apply a filter to each dataset to remove certain rows where country=="Belgium-Luxemburg". However, I receive an error. My code and the error are below.

```
datasets <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")
my_func <- function(x) {
  x <- x %>%
   filter(!country %in% c("Belgium-Luxembourg"))
}
lapply(datasets, my_func)
```

```
Error code: Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Note that I don't receive this error when I apply the filter to each dataset individually.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what's happening: your `datasets` vector is a character vector, not a list of data frames (the latter is what you want). That is, `"df1"` is just a character string, not a data frame. So use `datasets <- list(df1, df2, df3)`

Comment: thanks, @heds1, i don't receive the error anymore. However, it seems that the lapply function has not worked. I still find rows associated with country==Belgium-Luxembourg in all my dataframes. I wonder if I'm missing out any other steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `mget` to get actual list objects and return the final output from the function.

```
library(dplyr)

datasets <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")

my_func <- function(x) {
  x %>% filter(!country %in% c("Belgium-Luxembourg"))
}

result <- lapply(mget(datasets), my_func)
```

To see those changes in original dataframe use

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: I get the error 
Error in UseMethod("mget", client) : 
  no applicable method for 'mget' applied to an object of class "list"

Comment: That is because you changed `datasets <- c("df1", "df2", "df3")` to `datasets <- list(df1, df2, df3)`.

Comment: that's right but when I don't do that, i get the same error for class "character". i.e., "Error in UseMethod("mget", client) : 
  no applicable method for 'mget' applied to an object of class "character""

Comment: Do you have another `mget` function in your environment? Try using `base::mget` instead. If you have changed `datasets` to `datasets <- list(df1, df2, df3)` then you don't need `mget` and you can do `result <- lapply(datasets, my_func)` and then use `list2env` to see those changes in actual dataframes.